# WSO2 Micro Integration Socket Hang Up

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I have a problem. I am using WSO2 Micro Integration 4.1. I am sending request after "STATE_DESCRIPTION = Socket Timeout occurred after accepting the request headers and the request body, INTERNAL_STATE = REQUEST_DONE, DIRECTION = REQUEST, CAUSE_OF_ERROR = Connection between the client and the EI timeouts, HTTP_URL = /api/v1/test, HTTP_METHOD = POST, SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 180000, CLIENT_ADDRESS = /127.0.0.1:52694" is return my console and Error: socket hang up is return from postman. I tried http.connection.disable.keepalive=true in passthru-http.properties. I need help.

I tried http.connection.disable.keepalive=true in passthru-http.properties

Comment: Did you check whether the endpoint is accessible from the MI server? (Firewalls, DNS resolutions etc?)

Comment: I am tring in my local so I don't think I'm going to be stuck with a resolutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the description suggests this happened due to connection got time out. If you are having slow performing backend you can increase the timeout so that the server will wait until the response.
As an example following is the config to increase the synapse global timeout.

```
[synapse_properties]
'synapse.global_timeout_interval'=3000
```

Please note that you need to add the configurations on the **deployment.toml** file not in the **passthru-http.properties** file.

In that case if you want to make suggested change on the keep-alive settings, Do it as follows on the **deployment.toml** file.

```
[transport.http]
socket_timeout = 180000   # timeout in milliseconds
disable_connection_keepalive = true
connection_timeout = 90000 # in milliseconds
```

Apart from Check whether the 52694 port is accessible too as the server is localhost means that it is the same server as the MI is running.